# how to calculate max possible stack size utilization

Tags: ida, idapython, stack

Is there any elegant way to calculate the maximum possible stack depth utilization of a program, using IDAPython?

currently my best approach is iterating through all functions and counting stack-increasing instructions.

Comment: Are you looking for the max depth available to the program or the max depth actually utilized by the program? Also, what OS are you focused on?

Comment: looking for max depth utilized by the program and it isn't OS dependent (lets say linux)

Comment: @YoavDanieli maximum depth actually utilized by a program is not the same as maximum possible stack depth utilization, as @NirIzr has pointed out. Please clarify what you are asking. Resource limits such as maximum stack size available to a process are OS dependent. See [`getrlimit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) for more on this.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i think @NirIzr clarified this form me :)

Comment: What's worse is, they're context-dependent even on a single OS. Taking Windows, the limits vary vastly between what's allowed for a thread in user mode, in kernel mode _without_ using user32 facilities and in kernel mode _with_ using said facilities. The only thing that works, by my experience, is guesstimation.

Answer (score 1):

IDAPython-function `get_frame_size(ea)` gives size of stack in bytes.
So you can get max stack through all available functions:

```
"0x%04X" % max(get_frame_size(f) for f in Functions(0, BADADDR))
```

Comment: Nite that it would be worth calculating the worst possible call depth (using cross references, likely as a directed graph). Special attention should be paid to recursive functions. You should also factor in a worst case for API calls.